# Python script does not execute correctly when calling another program with os.system('./myProgram')

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I have a python script calling another program with the `os.system` command. It is a very complex program which can be called in the Terminal using `./myProgram`. I want to automatically execute said program and do different stuff (which works fine) in between.

Somehow this works:

```
print('start')
os.system('ll')
print('end')
```

But calling the program with the python script:

```
print('start')
os.system('./myProgram')
print('end')
```

just executes `myProgram` without showing the `print` statements. `myProgram` itself displays information in the terminal.
Later I want to do more than just `print` something in between.

I tried using the `subprocess` module:

```
print('start')
subprocess.call('./myProgram', shell = True)
print('end')
```

which shows the same results as the `os.system` module.

Which properties of a program do not allow my python script to run properly?
And how can I call another program with my python script, execute said program and continue with the script afterwards?

Comment: Some more information might be helpful.  What is the operating system platform?  How was myProgram constructed?  Is it a Python script?  Can you run it from a command line interface and see the output?  You said it is running without showing output.  How can you tell it is running?  Have you checked what current working directory an os.system or subprocess.call process runs in?  Are you doing anything that might redirect the standard output stream?

Answer (score 0):

u can always use a safe and secure way to call it

if u want to call app.py in the folder scripts_folder

just write:

```
from scripts_folder import app
```

Now if u have a def inside app.py for example my_def_example() u can call it by writing:

```
app.my_def_example()
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem ist, that myProgram is a very complex program which I can call in my Ubuntu operating system using the terminal with the command `./myProgram`. I want to automatically execute said program multiple times and do different stuff (which works fine) in between.